# Textfield Align Input Text Center

Tags: android, eclipse, alignment, textfield

I am making an android application. There, I have a textfield. All I want is to make it so when the user enters a text, it is aligned in the center of the textfield and not on the left as it is. I have made some search but I have found nothing about textfields. Thanks a lot

Comment: use android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

And when ever you post the question post the relevant code.